# Generate XSD from XML using xmlbeans, inst2xsd and Maven

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd

I have an XML file I want to generate an XSD schema from, using [xmlbeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/), specifically [inst2xsd](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd). I'd like to package the script so it can be run via Maven.
I could not find any documentation how to run inst2xsd when installing xmlbeans using Maven.
This is my `pom.xml` so far:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.wolkenarchitekt</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-to-xsd</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Installing this via `mvn install` works. Just for the reference - not important for the answer - I'm building it via Docker, so I'm using OpenJDK14:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14-slim
RUN mkdir -p /opt/workspace
WORKDIR /opt/workspace
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn install
```

Now how do I run the executable for `inst2xsd` after installing xmlbeans via Maven?

Comment: Generating an xsd is usually a one-off activity, so you don't have to do it in your project's development platform. ie, there are various tools you can use to do it (online and installed). Keep in mind that you will want to have a fairly complete example XML document to do the generation with, so that all the possible structures are accounted for in your xsd. Also, two different xsd's may be different but equivalent.

Comment: @Bryn thanks for the comment, to elaborate on my problem: I need to re-generate the XSD quite often as the XML is written by an external program in a way I cannot anticipate. I want/need to automate this process, so I cannot rely on some website. Furthermore I don't want to depend on a "installed tool".
So far the approach presented in the answer here works perfectly for my use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) to invoke the class `Inst2Xsd`. This class is the one actually called from the `inst2xsd` shell script.

If you do not need `xmlbeans` in your project - once your XSD is generated - you can event define this dependency only for that task.

Consider the following XML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<breakfast_menu>
  <food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    <calories>650</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
    <calories>600</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
    <calories>950</calories>
  </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

In the example we will name it `food-menu.xml` and save it in `src/main/resources`.

You can generate the XML schema as follows (the following example is derived from the code that you can find in the plugin [documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html)):

```xml
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
          <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
          <mainClass>org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.Inst2Xsd</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <!-- Add as many arguments as you need -->
            <argument>-outDir</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
            <argument>-validate</argument>
            <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/food-menu.xml</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

Just run `mvn exec:java` from your terminal or command line and the schema will be generated according to the arguments passed to `Inst2Xsd`.

The use of docker should not be a problem.

Comment: Perfect - thanks to this answer, I could complete my fully automated XML to XSD (+XSD to Python models) generator: https://github.com/wolkenarchitekt/traktor-nml-utils/tree/xsdata-xmlbeans/xml_to_xsd

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that the response has been helpful. By the way, very interesting project!